# How to resolve an error when uploading an image with AWS on iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, amazon-cognito

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZ54fH8AFUk) which involves uploading a UIImage to an s3 bucket using cognito for authentication. I am able to connect to cognito because my device is showing in the identity pool. However, when I try to upload the image to a bucket, I get this error:

```
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSGeneralErrorDomain Code=3 "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." UserInfo=0x17dc0f40 {NSLocalizedDescription=The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.}
```

The cognito authentication policy looks like this:

```
    {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
    "Action": [
        "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        "cognito-sync:*",
        "s3:*"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
}]
}
```

The code for setting up the credentials looks like this:

```
    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
                                                      credentialsWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                      accountId:@"#######"
                                                      identityPoolId:@"######"
                                                      unauthRoleArn:@"#####"
                                                      authRoleArn:@"######"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                      credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider]
```

and the code for uploading the image to s3 looks like this:

```
    NSString *tempPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:YES];


NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:tempPath];

AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = @"##########";
//uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPublicRead;
uploadRequest.key = @"image.png";
//uploadRequest.contentType = @"image/png";
uploadRequest.body = url;

uploadRequest.uploadProgress =^(int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend){
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
};

AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", task.error);
    }else{
        //success
        NSLog(@"success");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:nil];
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

Comment: What's the version of the SDK you are using? You should use the latest version of the SDK. Does your bucket contain any special characters? Also, you should enable the verbose logging by calling `[AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelVerbose;`.

Comment: Fixed it by re-adding the SDK. I had v2.0.5 for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following is code for upload image on amazon s3 also contain description follow step by step.

```
- (void)uploadToS3{
    // get the image from a UIImageView that is displaying the selected Image
    UIImage *img = _selectedImage.image;

    // create a local image that we can use to upload to s3
    NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    // once the image is saved we can use the path to create a local fileurl
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    // next we set up the S3 upload request manager
    _uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    // set the bucket
    _uploadRequest.bucket = @"s3-demo-objectivec";
    // I want this image to be public to anyone to view it so I'm setting it to Public Read
    _uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPublicRead;
    // set the image's name that will be used on the s3 server. I am also creating a folder to place the image in
    _uploadRequest.key = @"foldername/image.png";
    // set the content type
    _uploadRequest.contentType = @"image/png";
    // we will track progress through an AWSNetworkingUploadProgressBlock
    _uploadRequest.body = url;

    __weak ViewController *weakSelf = self;

    _uploadRequest.uploadProgress =^(int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend){
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            weakSelf.amountUploaded = totalBytesSent;
            weakSelf.filesize = totalBytesExpectedToSend;
            [weakSelf update];

        });
    };

    // now the upload request is set up we can creat the transfermanger, the credentials are already set up in the app delegate
    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
    // start the upload
    [[transferManager upload:_uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

        // once the uploadmanager finishes check if there were any errors
        if (task.error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", task.error);
        }else{// if there aren't any then the image is uploaded!
            // this is the url of the image we just uploaded
            NSLog(@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3-demo-objectivec/foldername/image.png");
        }

        return nil;
    }];

}
```

Please refer more detail for [sledgedev Blog](http://sledgedev.com/aws-s3-image-upload-using-aws-sdk-for-ios-v2/)

Comment: The writer of this made the video I was referring to. This is how my code looks, I just don't have upload progress doing anything. This doesn't help

Comment: @GeeGoldz can you please double check credentials(accountId etc).

Comment: I double checked the credentials and everything is correct. Also, the credentials provided in the app delegate must be correct because I am able to be authenticated via my device being added to the identity pool. I'm thinking there is an issue with my upload method or some settings in the AWS portal